# How to remove duplicate copies of all kinds of files from another directory

Tags: rsync, duplicate-files

I have 2 directories on separate drives: A and B.  A contains 680GB (around 2,500,000 items) and B about 400GB (around 2,000,000 items). All of B should be contained in A, the difference being about 500,000 .dmg .img and .iso files and associated text and .odt files detailing their contents.  How can I eliminate the files in A that are already held in B?  Is this a job for rsync or fdupes?  If so, what would the command line look like?
Any help would be much appreciated as disk A is very short of space.
Tks
jg

Comment: Sadly no, it's a different question.  It involves removing files from A that are already contained in B, in a similar relative [path].  There may be valid duplicates within A and within B that need to remain.  It does not relate to a single file type or class, but all kinds of stuff including .img .pdf .mpv etc etc

Comment: I guess I might be able to use meld or view the directories side by side on screen but that would take forever.

Comment: The question currently has 8 answers, all with at least 2 upvotes. Most (if not all) of the answer don't have anything to do with specific file types. I doubt whether you have gone through those answers in ~10 minutes. Take your time and read them all. P.S. I would personally suggest FSlint (second most upvoted answer).

Comment: pomsky, thankyou.  2 points:  1) I read that thread before I decided to post my question, and 2) you haven't taken the trouble to read my question.

Comment: Both are unsubstantiated.